# Can you block Avada Kevadra with a Patronus charm?

Tags: harry-potter, patronus-charm, avada-kedavra

[In my question here,](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125749/can-you-touch-an-animal-from-the-patronus-charm) I asked if Patronuses were corporeal or not. The answer was that they are decidedly so, and can interact with the physical world.

Now my question is if they are indeed corporeal and can be touched and moved, can they block the curse from Avada Kedavra?

> "You produced a fully fledged Patronus?"
>
> "Yes," said Harry, "because -"
>
> "A corporeal Patronus?"
>
> "A - what?" said Harry.
>
> "Your Patronus had a clearly defined form? I mean to say, it was more than just vapor or smoke?"
>
> (Order of the Phoenix)

Comment: Not too sure if it's worth an answer but: Avada Kedavra is a flash of light. A patronus has to form when cast. By the time an opponent has cast the avada kedavra, how long would it take for a patronus to form large enough to block? Also some patronus forms could be small, so not large enough to block. In my opinion, it's possible but not practical.

Comment: Aren't patronii linked to the life force of the conjurer? That seems a flaw in blocking an instant death spell with it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It might be possible to block Avada Kedavra with a Patronus. Canon doesn't suggest this anywhere, but there are other situations in which Avada Kedavra has been blocked or diverted. For example:

- In *Goblet of Fire*, Voldemort's Avada Kedavra is blocked, or at least held at bay, by the Priori Incantatem spell, which can disallow wands with dual cores (cores from the same source, as Harry and Voldemort's wands had) from landing their target(s) when a spell is cast.
- Pure love seems to be capable of diverting Avada Kedavra, as Lily Potter demonstrated when she gave up her life for Harry. Voldemort was subsequently unable to kill Harry with Avada Kedavra after Lily died, because he was protected by the magic of pure love.
- Dumbledore is able to use corporeal objects, such as statues and whatnot, to divert Avada Kedavra during his duel with Voldemort at the Ministry for Magic in *Order of the Phoenix*.
- **The Dark Lord** mentions the Lethifold in the comments below, and it's a great point to consider. *Fantastic Beasts* indicates the Patronus is more than mere wisps of mist, as it actually uses its horns to repel a Lethifold, which *seems* to be a corporeal being -- a Lethifold has volume, it can eat humans and perhaps beasts as well, and it can physically digest its prey. From *Fantastic Beasts*, recounting a Lethifold attack on Flavius Belby: *I performed the Patronus Charm. Almost at once I felt fresh air upon my face. **I looked up to see that deathly shadow being thrown into the air upon the horns of my Patronus. It flew across the room and slithered swiftly out of sight.***

**As the Patronus is a corporeal creature, and this *is* canonically correct, I don't think we can rule out the possibility that a Patronus might be useful against Avada Kedavra.**

There's no canon example of this happening, but Potterverse does have strong elements of possibility.

Comment: I think it's likely that the state of matter is important when dealing with *Avada Kedavra*. Dumbledore blocked it with statues of marble, not with water. In my opinion, though a patronus is corporeal, I think it's pretty wispy, like an intricate smoke shape. The killing curse would likely go right through the first hole/gap it found.

Comment: @TylerH Corporeal: adjective
1.
of the nature of the physical body; bodily.

Comment: @Anoplexian That doesn't really change anything; 'physical' (read: corporeal) just means matter of some kind you can interact with. Smoke is matter.

Comment: @Tylerh Refer to the link in the question. The accepted answer addresses this with canon sources.

Comment: @Anoplexian: I don't think you are interpreting that definition correctly. A wet paper bag has a "physical body" and is thus corporeal. But it's not going to save you from anything that might do you any amount of harm. While a Patronus is corporeal, what you're really trying to find out is "is it solid enough and durable enough to stop/block a killing curse?" I kind of doubt it.

Comment: @Ellesedil A spell COULD plausibly (we haven't thrown Avada Kevadra at a paper bag before) be blocked by a paper bag considering. There's of course spells that affect the natural world (Bombarda, Reducto, and other spells that cause....rather explosive results), but AK isn't one of these and therein lies the plausibility of a blocked spell (Provided you're not holding the bag, as clothing doesn't seem to block it). I am interested in the actual effects of AK though, as it seems to not affect inanimate objects, but there's no "armor" one can wear against it. Voldie can't get them headshots. ;)

Comment: @Anoplexian It does affect inanimate objects. It sets fire to the security guard's desk at the Ministry and it shatters the centaur statue into a hundred pieces (though it just merely glances off the wizard statue). And those are properly solid objects, not wispy, soft, light objects. As for Patronuses, we simply don't know how corporeal they are in this sense. The fact that they can interact with the real, solid world doesn't necessarily mean that they are themselves solid enough to hit your head on if you walk into one, for instance. That's not how magic in the Potterverse works.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet If you can provide some quotes for those, I'd definitely redact my previous statement!

Comment: @Anoplexian Both are from the fight in the Atrium between Voldemort and Dumbledore at the end of _OotP_. The one that glances off the wizard is the first one (when Harry doesn't know Dumbledore is there to help him yet). I think maybe that's the same one that ricochets off and hits the security guy’s desk and sets fire to it. It's all in those three or four pages, anyway. (Don't have access to the books right now.)

Answer (score 5):

### No, on two grounds.

Firstly, the Patronus has one very specific primary function: to defend its caster from Dementors. (Granted, they also have a secondary function as messengers). A Patronus can't be used as a generic counter-curse or defensive spell in the same way that *Protego* can.

Secondly, you can't block Avada Kedavra with **anything**.

> "Ah," said Moody, another slight smile twisting his lop-sided mouth. "Yes, the last and the worst. *Avada Kedavra*...the killing curse."
>
> "Not nice," he said calmly. "Not pleasant. And there's no counter-curse. **There's no blocking it.** Only one known person has ever survived it, and he's sitting right in front of me."
>
> *Goblet of Fire, Chapter 14, The Unforgivable Curses*

Harry survived *Avada Kedavra* three times, the first time because of his mother's sacrifice and the other two times because of wandlore. These were the exceptions, not the rules.

Comment: But you can hide behind things... - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/36462/20774

Comment: @Richard I'd count that as 'hiding', not 'blocking'!

Comment: @TheDarkLord So if the question was "Can you hide behind a patronus so Avarda Kedavra doesn't hit you?" would you still give the same answer?

Comment: Dumbledore "blocked" it with the statues in the Ministry, and we know curses can be deflected by other curses. Given that the Patronus becomes physical would it not stand to reason that they are solid? Also, in the question in the question, it's not solely for Dementors.

Comment: @Bellerephon, I'm open to the possibility that I may be wrong but my understanding of a Patronus is that it forms a physical barrier between the castor and a Dementor that forces the Dementor back. I wouldn't have thought that a Patronus would influence **any** form of spell one way or another. The curse (in this case Avada Kedavra) would travel through the Patronus unimpaired. So yes my answer would be the same.

Comment: @Anoplexian, Dumbledore put a physical barrier in the way of the curse so that it didn't hit Harry. It wasn't a counter-curse. It was just throwing things in the way! The conclusion I would draw is that physical objects can protect you from AD (they can stop you getting hit). But that Patronuses only act as physical barriers to Dementors. So a Patronus wouldn't act as a physical barrier to anything else (including a curse). If someone throws AD at you hide behind a wall, don't cast a Patronus! In other words, my answer is different to that others gave you in your linked question.

Comment: @TheDarkLord There is an example in Fantastic Beasts where a patronus hits a beast so they can affect things physically.

Comment: @TheDarkLord Take a look at the link in the question. It has canonical references that although difficult to cast, Patronus' are very much corporeal in general.

Comment: @Anoplexian. I've taken a look at it. The key quote seems I think to be the one with Madam Bones. Corporeal Patronus is contrasted with "a fully fledged Patronus" with "a clearly defined form" which is "more than just vapour and smoke". I understand that as the difference between the flimsy, inaffective Patronus that Harry was able to create in his lessons with Lupin in comparison with the fully-fledged stag he was able to create at the end of Prisoner of Azkaban. So corporeal in context means 'substantial' not 'material, things will bounce off it'. Though clearly it's material for Dementors.

Comment: Maybe I should post an answer in the other page to explain more fully?

Comment: Corporeal: adjective
1.
of the nature of the physical body; bodily.

Comment: @Anoplexian That's the dictionary definition that corporeal relates to bodily physicality. I'd suggest it doesn't get us very far in defining the perimeters of what a Patronus is or isn't capable of. For me, it's physical in relation to being a barrier against Dementors. In all other instances it's ethereal, even when in its 'fully-fledged' form. There's more discussion in [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15354/what-are-the-rules-governing-how-a-patronus-can-interact-with-the-physical-world?rq=1) question.

Comment: The corporeality of the patronus is canon. The speculation as to why they don't move things is irrelevant, as it's based on the movies (and therefore not quite canon).

Comment: @Anoplexian. For me, the reason that a Patronus can ride across lakes without making a ripple or walk through snow without leaving a mark or go through a tent without making a hole is because they are in very nature ethereal (unless they are confronted with a Dementor or, I guess, a lethifold). For me, the corporeality is a red herring since we mean two different things by it. We may have to accept a difference of opinion on this point!

Answer (score 3):

**Perhaps, but it probably wouldn't be a good idea.**

Firstly, from a practical point of view: you would likely need to have summoned your Patronus ahead of time, since my understanding is that when first summoned it is only a sort of mist and requires a few seconds to take full corporeal form.  In most cases, your adversary is unlikely to allow you the time to do this, and if they do, it would probably be easier and safer to disapparate.

Even if your Patronus *is* already present, it isn't clear how quickly and precisely the wizard can control its actions - getting it to jump in front of you at just the right time might be challenging.  (Admittedly, this would not be as much of a problem if you have a large Patronus like Harry's.)

More importantly, it seems to me that a Patronus is a corporeal representation of your inner being.  If it is corporeal enough to block Avada Kedavra, it is corporeal enough to be affected by it, and it seems very likely that this would have a severe effect on you.  (It seems even more likely that Avada Kedavra would be unable to affect a Patronus, but in that case it wouldn't be blocked by one, either.)

Absolute best case scenario, it would destroy the happy memory you used to cast it (which might be worth it if it saves your life) but it seems more likely that it would cripple you severely enough that death would be preferable - perhaps you would lose the ability to ever be happy, for example, or perhaps it would outright destroy your soul.  (The latter is my guess, given the relationship between the Patronus spell and Dementors.)

Given the risks involved, I doubt that anyone has been willing to experiment.  So this is probably an unresolved question, even from an in-universe perspective.

Comment: I don’t think there’s any indication anywhere that destroying a Patronus (if at all possible) would have any effect whatsoever on the caster. The Patronus _spell_ requires happiness, through focusing on a happy memory, but there’s nothing to indicate that the Patronus itself takes any of the caster’s memory or happiness with it into the real, corporeal world. Your first point is good: it would take far too long and be far too slow to use a Patronus as an actual defence against _Avada Kedavra_; but I don’t think your second point holds up.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: there's clearly *some* sort of connection between the caster's soul (or a reasonable facsimile thereof) and the Patronus; if it were just an external entity you were conjuring up, you'd be able to conjure whatever sort of animal you liked. Of course the connection might not be as strong as I'm speculating, but in the absence of any WoG evidence either way, I think it a reasonable guess. IMO it fits better with the overall theme of Harry Potter than assuming that having your Patronus destroyed would be harmless, or that a Patronus could block AK without being affected by it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Another point to make is that AD doesn't affect or destroy your soul. It kills your body instantly, allowing your soul to go "on" (as Dumbledore puts it). So AD poses no threat to a Patronus, only to the person its aimed at. I agree with Janus Bahs Jacquet. The Patronus needs a happy memory to be activated but is not tied to the soul. Hence, Umbridge's Patronus disappears in DH not because her soul is hurt but because she's been stunned unconscious.

Comment: @TheDarkLord: actually I think that's the most likely scenario, that AK would have no effect on a Patronus.  But in that case it wouldn't be blocked by one, either.  Sorry, thought that was obvious - I'll edit it in.